# What is the average time and distance needed to reach cruising height?

Tags: aircraft-performance, airbus-a320

I am trying to compare trains with airplanes and the distances where taking a train is more viable than an airplane. I guess this would depend on the type of plane, but the Airbus 320 seems like a common enough plane in Europe so I have something along that type in mind.

As far as I know, it would be a good model for airplanes to separate the takeoff and landing phase, where they cover less ground and does take appreciable time on shorter hauls and the cruising phase. I found average speed for the latter but I don't know how much time takeoff takes and how much ground the aircraft can cover during this. Same goes for landing, so my question is, how much time do these take and how far does the aircraft get during these?

I'm also assuming that when looking at city center to city center travel times, taking a plane has about a three hour overhead (airports are far and it takes quite a long time to get in, security check and all), but if anybody actually knows some statistics on this I'd be much obliged :)

Comment: There is a simple rule of thumb in Europe. For domestic trips, trains always make more sense. For international trips, airplanes make more sense. The reasons are time, pricing and heavy competition in international vs domestic routes. Airliner performance does not play into this.

Comment: I am right now only interested in time, nothing else. Also, your rule of thumb might apply for Spain, but Vienna - Budapest is already faster and cheaper with a train and there's nothing really fancy going between the two :)

Comment: "Takeoff" and "landing" have rather specific meanings in aviation, and are very short in duration. You are probably more interested in the climb and descent portions of the flight.

Comment: When flying, nearly no time is spent below average ground speed of even a high-speed train, so in reality flying speed isn’t the controlling parameter, I believe... nonetheless, good question!

Comment: I think this question needs to be restated, the title asks a specific question but the post's body seems confused.

Comment: @fbence What makes you think I am talking about Spain? Vienna to Budapest is indeed the exception. And about the only exception. If you are only interested in time, it takes 45 min by air, 2.5 hours by train, so if you have time to waste... :)

Comment: @JuanJimenez Is that rule from your left thumb or your right thumb?

Comment: @koyovis Still confused, eh? 

Comment: @JuanJimenez Spain: your name and that I just spent a lot of time taking trains all around Spain :D Vienna - Budapest: well, it takes 2.5 hours by train, while it takes almost 2.5 hours to get on a plane, so definitely a lot faster by train :D

Comment: @aCVn Sorry, yeah the descent and climb is what I'm interested in because it seems to me that it is a slower part than cruising and on short flights I thought it might be a pretty relevant part.

Comment: @CptReynolds Yes, I guess it's faster almost always, than a train, but my thinking was that on shorter trips the climb/descent, which seems to me to be slower than cruising, might make up a large portion of the flight and so didn't want to cheat in favor of planes by taking the average cruising speed for the entire distance.

Comment: Yes that’s good thinking. On most aircraft and flights, it’s within 5 minutes after takeoff that 250kts (indicated airspeed) is reached, which is higher in true airspeed depending on altitude, but could be even lower in ground speed due to wind influence. Up to 10000ft, most flights are limited to 250kts. Depending on aircraft type, above that, something around 280-300kts indicated airspeed is flown up to the altitude where that speed equates the Mach number flown from that altitude to cruise altitude (something in the Ma .72 to .82 range will probably work). Descent is similar in reverse.

Comment: @fbence You got it wrong by 4000 miles.

Answer (score 3):

I answer directly to the title of the question:

> What is the average time and distance needed to reach cruising height?

The Takeoff takes very little time, but the climb phase depends on the cruise flight level clearance. Assuming you climb with a vario of 2000ft/min with an average IAS of 200kts. The time to reach the cruise level is equal to:

(Cruise level in ft - takeoff terrain elevation if ft)/2000, the result is in minutes.

So if the departure is at sea level and the cruise altitude is at 30000ft, the climb phase will take : 30000/2000=15min

The descent till arrival could be more complicated because in addition to the pure descent you have to level before intercepting the approach phase which occurs relatively at lower speed. If you are lucky, not having to hold above the airport, the total descent might take 20 to 30 minutes

Routes are not necessarily straight lines, nevertheless you may assume an average cruise True speed of 500 knots.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't think I actually understand your answer, which is probably due to my lack of knowledge in aviation. I'm guessing that the 500 kts/hour would be true for cruising. You also said climbing and descending will take about say 40 minutes in total. I'm assuming during this 40 minutes the average speed is below 500 kts/hour, so what would be a good estimate for the amount of ground covered in that 40 minutes?

Comment: After surfaces retraction the speed goes rapidly to 250 kts indicated, but at sea level no real difference between true speed and indicated airspeed. However at cruise altitude even though being at about 250knots indicated, your true speed may be about 500 knots. So you may assume during climb and descent  phases an average true speed of 375 knots. You are right, these phases should be calculated separately, I do apologize.  For very long flights roughly we can consider an average true speed of 500 knots, I will correct.

Comment: "500 kts/hr" would be a (weirdly expressed) rate of accelleration, as knots is already nautical miles per hour, thus kts/hr would be nm/h/h.

Comment: Yes indeed, I wanted to write miles/hour instead of kts, to be clearer ....unhappily I did a lapsus

Comment: I thought it  was addressed to me, I am sure fbence did a lapsus

Comment: yeah, I messed up the knots/hour :) @user40476, if you add the correction to the answer I will except, thank you!